# question on center surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Below is Figure 2-33 from Struik: Lectures on Classical Differential Geometry, page 95 showing two examples of surfaces that form the loci of the centers of principal curvatures. To each surface there are two such loci, and from Rodrigues' theorem it follows that these loci are developable surfaces tangent to the surface normals if and only if the normals lie along the principal curvature lines on such as are shown as $C_1$ and $C_2$ the Figure.

My question is what happens if we iterate the procedure and generate another of pair of center surfaces for each center surface. Does this converge in any sense?

[image]